# Subscribing Users to MailChimp using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, mailchimp

I've been tasked with developing a simple package to post from a newsletter signup form to MailChimp. Easy enough for me to do in PHP, but this has to be in ASP.NET, which I don't know at all.

I've found my way to PerceptiveMCAPI, gotten my API keys, my list id, and my form fields set up, but I just have no idea how I'm supposed to create the actual listSubscribe command. The only examples I can find are for listBatchSubscribe, which I haven't been able to water down to only work for a single iteration.

Please help! I need to be pointed in the right direction, or given an example of how to actually build this command.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Hope you understand c# code.

```
listSubscribe cmd = new listSubscribe();

listSubscribeParms newlistSubscribeParms = new listSubscribeParms 
{ 
    apikey = apikey,
    id = listid,
    email_address = "test@gmail.com",
    merge_vars =  new Dictionary<string, object>(),
    double_optin = false,
    email_type = EnumValues.emailType.html,
    replace_interests = true,
    send_welcome = false,
    update_existing = true 
};            

listSubscribeInput newlistSubscribeInput = new listSubscribeInput(newlistSubscribeParms);

var subscribeSuccess = cmd.Execute(newlistSubscribeInput);
```

The `listSubscribe`, `listSubscribeParms`, `listSubscribeInput` come from the  [PerceptiveMCAPI library](http://perceptivemcapi.codeplex.com/).

hope this helps.

if it does, then don't forget to mark as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the VB code that works great for me. The above code didnt convert well for me...

You need to get this http://perceptivemcapi.codeplex.com/
If using VS pro you can just copy the two dlls into the bin, in express i think you need to import them/reference them or something!

Your need to do these imports

```
Imports PerceptiveMCAPI
Imports PerceptiveMCAPI.Types
Imports PerceptiveMCAPI.Methods
```

then this code...

```
Dim cmd As New listSubscribe()

Dim newlistSubscribeParms As New listSubscribeParms()
newlistSubscribeParms.apikey = "YourApiKeyFromMailChimp"
newlistSubscribeParms.id = "YourListIdFromMailChimp"
newlistSubscribeParms.email_address = "NewEmailToAddToList@domain.com"
newlistSubscribeParms.double_optin = False
newlistSubscribeParms.email_type = EnumValues.emailType.html
newlistSubscribeParms.replace_interests = True
newlistSubscribeParms.send_welcome = False
newlistSubscribeParms.update_existing = True

Dim newlistSubscribeInput As New listSubscribeInput(newlistSubscribeParms)
Dim subscribeSuccess = cmd.Execute(newlistSubscribeInput)
```

Simples!